# Physically at the center of the universe looking out--Particular kind of existential angst?

Tags: terminology

I know I'm not the center of the universe. But physically, I am the center, from purely my own perspective, looking out at the world and all other beings. The *occasional* angst I get is: Why am I the person who is physically at the center looking out? Is this about the "meaning of life"? I don't care about the meaning of life. I only wonder why I'm at the physical center of it, looking out. Do others feel that way?

Is there a specific term for this?

Comment: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would call it "interstitial angst".

Comment: This isn’t a question about the English language.

Comment: Since you realize that it’s just from your perspective you must also realize that ***everyone*** thinks they’re at the center looking out.   So the question is, “Who’s looking in??”

Comment: @Jim - The Peeping Tom.

Comment: ... Egocentricity